# Wordpress JSON Auth API generate_auth_cookie method cookie value

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies, setcookie, wordpress-json-api

I need help with how to use the cookie generated using Wordpress JSON Auth API. I am unable to get the hashed cookie but get what appears to be the header. When I set this cookie on my javascript client it doesn't work obviously.

Workinkg Cookie:-

```
admin%7C1553159233%7CpUwRykRFZMab2XJnUwqBeO1RX4xtLfxNTc7VZmVIEsq%7C019d8c6b7dc02a0ee283c3a60455aaeb72e92526baf0485f46b03fe5a48215ec
```

Wordpress JSON Api Cookie:-

```
admin|1554465599|rdj5XyQOeGMwjv26qsfs1PeIbtIMcFlbmeoDNfDVMPk|f39bcfce53943fcbfbba0cef65c13ec491f07cba067e33e2be54045e4cc771d4
```

Do I have to convert the cookie I get from the Wordpress API route and then set the cookie on my JavaScript client?

I am using the following API endpoint to generate the cookie

```
https://example.com/api/user/generate_auth_cookie/
```